# QML: item properties from global mouse handler

Tags: c++, qml

On my qml ui most clickable elements (buttons, combo, table entries) are enabled/disabled in respect to the current users access level. The element uses the standard 'isEnabled' property for enabling/disabling.

The new request is to show a message with the required access level when a disabled element is clicked.

One way would be to not use 'isEnabled' and handle the access in each onClick method. But this is boring ;-) and error prone.

My idea is to install a global event filter (in my C++ code) and check if the clicked element is disabled. If so then get some infos from the element and show the message.

Installing the 'eventFilter' worls, but I do not know how to find the clicked element from the passed object `obj`:

`eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)`

My idea in pseudo code:

```
guiElement = getClickedElement(obj);
if (element.isDisabled()) {
    showMessage();
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: Actually you say 'onClick' is boring and instead of that you want another kind of 'onClick' but in a much more complicated way. That besides that this behavior violates the general concept, I mean clicking on disabled control.

Comment: @folibis I did mean to change /each/ onClick is a boring bunch of work...  I see it as an help overlay that gives infos about the elements and does not perform any actions with the botton - beside reding properties. Like the questionmark cursor on Windows.